# Angular:- on mouse hover, show button on image(from *ngFor loop)

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<div *ngFor="let gallery of galleries; let i = index ">

      <img 
        [src]="imagesrc "
        alt="gallery thumbnail" (mouseenter)="enter(i)" (mouseleave)="leave(i)"/>

 <button class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="hoverIndex == i">EDIT</button>
  </div>


 public enter(i) {
    this.hoverIndex = i;
   }

   public leave(i) {
    this.hoverIndex = null;
   }
```

Above code works for show/hide functionality of  button on hover. But I need to add property to hovered image, such that it should fade out on hover and button should be on center of image (now it's appearing on the right side).

I cant use `posiiton:absolute` because it will disturb the order of images coming from `*ngFor`.

Answer (score 1):

I took away the angular code to show you how adding a few reusable classes to the elements you are outputting allow nice CSS effects like the hover/fade you are looking for.

```css
.gallery-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in; /* transition the opacity for nice fade */
}
.gallery-item:hover .gallery-img {
  opacity: 0; /* change opacity on wrapper div hover */
}
.gallery-button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/245" alt="gallery thumbnail" class="gallery-img" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary gallery-button">EDIT</button>
</div>
```